# c# Newtonsoft Cambiar la coma decimal por punto decimal

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, newtonsoft

El problema debe ser resuelto para que pueda funcionar en version NET 3.5

Tengo un Json con un campo en notacion decimal con punto.

```
{ "importe": 0.1 }
```

al parsearlo con la libreria NewtonSoft

```
JObject.Parse("{ 'importe': 0.1 }")["importe"].ToString()
```

me cambia el punto decimal por una coma
"0,1"

Necesito que me conserve el punto decimal y ademas que muestre dos decimales. Cuando intento dar un formato con ToString("0.00") o con String.Format() me lo devuelve con "0,10" o da error.

He probado con

```
double.Parse(JObject.Parse("{ 'importe': 0.1 }")["importe"].ToString()).ToString("0.00")
```

sigue devolviendome "0,10"

Tambien he probado con:

```
JObject.Parse("{ 'importe': 0.1 }")["importe"].ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("0.00")
```

devuelve error:

```
error CS1503: Argumento 1: no se puede convertir de 'System.Globalization.CultureInfo' a 'Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting'
```

y con:

```
double.Parse(JObject.Parse("{ 'importe': 0.1 }")["importe"].ToString()).ToString("0.00").ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

sigue devolviendo como "0,10"

y tambien con:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
string prueba2 = double.Parse(JObject.Parse("{ 'importe': 0.1 }")["importe"].ToString()).ToString("0.00");
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("es-ES");
```

sigue devolviendome "0,10"

Si hago lo siguiente:

```
double.Parse(JObject.Parse("{ 'importe': 0.1 }")["importe"].ToString()).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Me devuelve "0.1" Correcto !!! pero necesito que me muestre 2 decimales para que sea "0.10"

```
double.Parse(JObject.Parse("{ 'importe': 0.1 }")["importe"].ToString()).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("0.00")
```

Entonces me sale este error:

```
error CS1503: Argumento 1: no se puede convertir de 'string' a 'System.IFormatProvider'
```

Otra prueba ha sido con String.Format()

```
String.Format("{0:0.00}", double.Parse(JObject.Parse("{ 'importe': 0.1 }")["importe"].ToString())).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

sigue saliendo "0,10"

Comment: Lo mejor en este caso es cambiar  la cultura en  el hilo en el proceso de ejecución. Lo puedes hacer -> ` System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;` a partir de esta line ira con esta cultura para volver a canviar System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("es-ES");

Comment: @rexxarcat lo he provado y sigue devolviendome lo mismo "0,1"

Comment: Y qué tal si lo serializas con la clase JsonConvert o JsonSerializer?

Comment: @Mateo debo entrar un string Json no puedo crear una clase para que me la deserialize

Comment: Hola Popularian, el problema es que en la mayoría de los países de habla hispana, se usa la coma como separador de decimales, entonces o bien pasas el idioma de tu aplicación a algún anglosajón, o te creas un método tipo **aCadena( decimalParaConvertir );**.

Comment: @MarcePuente eso lo habia pensado, pero lo correcto seria que Newtonsoft me haga el Parse tal cual recibe el dato sin cambiar nada. Porque el importe puede tener tambien un numero con millares y decimales tal como 57,000.23 o 57 000.23

Comment: "Lo correcto sería".. podemos llegar a estar de acuerdo en eso, a los desarrolladores de Newtonsoft no les importa mucho, o le especificas a Newtonsoft que el idioma es inglés, o modificas lo que devuelve, no veo otro camino.

Comment: @MarcePuente le indico que el idioma es el ingles con CultureInfo tal y como he leido en otros comentarios pero como ves siempre me cambia el punto por la coma

Comment: @MarcePuente ya he visto el problema y es cuando quiero formatear el resultado que me devuelve Newtonsoft para que el resultado sea con 2 decimales en vez de uno. Es decir cuando añado ToString("0.00")

Answer (score 2):

Primero debes [Deserializar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to?pivots=dotnet-8-0) tu JSON, te recomiendo esta [pagina](https://app.quicktype.io/) que te convierte tu json a clase c#

```
 var json = "{\"importe\":0.1}";
 var deserialize = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Import>(json);

public class Import
{
  [JsonProperty("importe")]
  public double Importe { get; set; }
}
```

obteniendo como resultado , aqui puedes verlo [resultado](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VU4i8F)

```
respuesta 0.1
```

Comment: Necesito hacerlo dinamicamente sin crear antes ninguna clase porque el nombre del  campo del Json puede variar o ese campo estar en otra rama del Json.

Comment: Si cambia el nombre de `importe` entonces no se puede deserializar, ni tampoco podrías usar JObject, porque no se puede hacer dinámica, no se puede acceder a un json si no sabes cómo se va a llamar tu campo, siempre obtendrías un error

Comment: El nombre de importe o la rama se actualiza dinamicamente cada x tiempo por otro nombre o rama que se cual es porque me llega esa notificacion de cambio. Entonces solo me basta cambiarlo dentro del string. Si declaro una clase esta es fija y no la puedo cambiar.

Comment: @Popularfan mirando tu ejemplo que querías hacer, quedaría de esta manera `var ob = JsonNode.Parse(json);` , con esto accedes a tu JSON `var jos = ob?["importe"]?.ToString();` pero como te comento, si cambia el nombre importe, tendrás que cambiar el nombre también adentro del arreglo, porqué te marcaria error, al no existir , aquí te dejo la liga con el resultado https://dotnetfiddle.net/eIJdjk

Comment: necesito que el código corra sin problemas en NET 3.5 por lo que  no me sirve JsonNode

Comment: he visto el problema y es cuando quiero formatear el resultado que me devuelve Newtonsoft para que el resultado sea con 2 decimales en vez de uno. Es decir cuando añado ToString("0.00")

Comment: @Popularfan entonces solo cambialo por `JObject`, y deberias especificar que version de netcore estas usando, porque `JsonNode` es lo mismo que `JObject` , aqui tienes el resultado, el codigo deberia funcionar , ahi mismo puedes hacer la conversion a decimal, float, etc  https://dotnetfiddle.net/fKbUbr